# Facebook Conversion Pixel on Typeform.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I was curious how I could integrate the facebook conversion pixel on www.typeform.com

I want  it so that it counts as "1" when the Stripe payment is confirmed.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: It is blowing my mind that Typeform doesn't allow form submissions to be redirected to a custom URL (instead of the standard thank-you page) even for paying accounts.  This is a huge missed opportunity. http://helpcenter.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/202757838-Tracking-conversions

Answer (score 1):

This currently isn't possible. Typeform doesn't allow you to embed custom HTML/JS into their forms. They do, however, allow you to connect your Google Analytics account to track behavior on their forms.

Answer (score 1):

I came late but still will answer. If Typeform still doesn't have this, you can use 123FormBuilder instead. They allow custom HTML & JS code on forms. See this article: https://www.123formbuilder.com/docs/how-to-add-facebook-conversion-tracking-to-your-online-form/